# "Reset" switch statement after value is equal

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

I'd like to run my switch and if/else statement again after the buttons are clicked three times in total.

The current pressed code is for three buttons with each 1 value. If those (current pressed code) are equal to the global string that contains a 3 number value, the picture box color will change to forest green. This is my code:

```
        switch ((sender as Button).Text)
        {

            case "1":
                serialMonitor.PrintLine("1");
                currentPressedCode = currentPressedCode + "1";
                break;
            case "2":
                serialMonitor.PrintLine("2");
                currentPressedCode = currentPressedCode + "2";
                break;
            case "3":
                serialMonitor.PrintLine("3");
                currentPressedCode = currentPressedCode + "3";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }  if (buttonsPressed == 3)
        {
            if (currentPressedCode == vaultCode)
            {

                //vault open
                serialMonitor.PrintLine("vault");
                pcbGreen.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            // wrong code
            serialMonitor.PrintLine("wrong");
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong password"); // wrong password messagebox
            pcbRed.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
        }
```

Comment: So what's the question here?

Comment: How can I run this switch statement again after the button has been pressed 3 times? Now, it doesn't do anything after the button has been clicked 3 times.

Comment: Sounds like you want a `while` loop that checks `buttonsPressed` through each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you could accomplish this, but trying to keep your logic intact as much as possible:

```
switch ((sender as Button).Text)
{

    case "1":
        serialMonitor.PrintLine("1");
        currentPressedCode = currentPressedCode + "1";
        break;
    case "2":
        serialMonitor.PrintLine("2");
        currentPressedCode = currentPressedCode + "2";
        break;
    case "3":
        serialMonitor.PrintLine("3");
        currentPressedCode = currentPressedCode + "3";
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
if (buttonsPressed == 3)
{
    if (currentPressedCode == vaultCode)
    {

        //vault open
        serialMonitor.PrintLine("vault");
        pcbGreen.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;

    }
    else
    {
        // wrong code
        serialMonitor.PrintLine("wrong");
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong password"); // wrong password messagebox
        pcbRed.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;

    }
    buttonsPressed = 0;
    currentPressedCode = "";
}
```

The only changes I made were:

1. Moving your "Wrong Password" else block after the "Right Password"
   if block
2. Resetting `buttonsPressed` and the `currentPressedCode`
   after someone has typed in 3 numbers